# Setting up a Django form in 2 times

Tags: python, django

I can't achieve to make a form in 2 times. The values between the 2 forms does not seems to be saved.

Whenever the second form is submitted, it brings me back to the first one saying "This field is required."

I am trying to set up a Django form that works in 2 times :
The first one is asking the user to upload a file in a form.
Then, when submitted, there is a function that analyze the file (CSV) and get every values from a row.
It then ask the user, in a new form, to select every value he would like.
Then, when submitted, it executes a new function.

Here is what I've got so far :

```
views.py
if choice == '2':  
    site_choices = list(donneesLieux.keys())  # Get the site choices from donneesLieux

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'csv_choice_data' in request.session:
            csv_choice_data = request.session['csv_choice_data']
            form_site_selection = SiteSelectionForm(request.POST, site_choices=site_choices, initial=csv_choice_data)
            if form_site_selection.is_valid():
                selected_sites = form_site_selection.cleaned_data['selected_sites']

                # Merge data for selected sites
                merged_data = []
                for site in selected_sites:
                    merged_data.extend(donneesLieux[site])

                output_filename = 'example.xlsx'
                file_bilan = doExtract(merged_data, output_filename, 1)
                with open(file_bilan, 'rb') as f:
                    response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename="{output_filename}"'
                    return response
        else:
            form_site_selection = SiteSelectionForm(request.POST, site_choices=site_choices)
    else:
        if 'csv_choice_data' in request.session:
            csv_choice_data = request.session['csv_choice_data']
            form_site_selection = SiteSelectionForm(site_choices=site_choices, initial=csv_choice_data)
        else:
            form_site_selection = SiteSelectionForm(site_choices=site_choices)

    return render(request, 'site_selection.html', {'form': form_site_selection})
```

and in the forms

```
statform.py

class FileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(label='Fichier CSV', widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'accept': '.csv'}))
    choice = forms.ChoiceField(label='Choix', choices=[('bilan', 'Bilan'), ('mediateur', 'Médiateur')])
    
class SiteSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, site_choices=[], **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['selected_sites'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=[(site, site) for site in site_choices],
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        )
```

I'm quite lost after trying for a while.
Thanks for the help !